# Field in mathematics for forecasting price of stock markets

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, finance, computational-mathematics

Hi i'm just learned somethings about technical analysis and some stuff about indicators?

Here is my questions:

Does Technical analysis based on Mathematics so we can trust it?

Which filed of mathematics help us for doing analysis and forecasting price movment in financal markets ?

Can we really predict price movment with mathematics or other sciences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not my area of expertise, but my understanding is that one uses [Ito calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus) to write down "differential equations" of random variables. We model markets based on such differential equations. My understanding is that a broader class of models known as [Levy processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) can also be used.

A famous model in this domain is known as the [Black-Scholes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation) which governs price evolution in certain types of options.

In general, looking at [quantitative finance / mathematical finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_finance) is the keyword you are looking for.

Since I believe you are a programmer, [this collection of IPython notebooks that build up the theory of quantitative finance](https://github.com/cantaro86/Financial-Models-Numerical-Methods) is invaluable.

Comment: Itô calculus is very different from "[technical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis)", with the latter being the idea that previous patterns repeat themselves, rather like saying you can predict what happens next a roulette wheel by looking at what previously happened after three reds followed by three blacks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been posted, [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1717163) gives a nice overview of the areas of mathematical finance, and what type of mathematics are involved in each.

As far as technical analysis goes, I've only seen [momentum indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_(technical_analysis)) referenced as viable strategies in some cases within academia. Though, no one would be quick to publish results if they found otherwise.